# How to select first item after filtering ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, icollectionview

I'm binding a ListView to an ICollectionView in my viewmodel. The ICollectionView has some predefined filters that are applied when you click some buttons. However I cannot seem to find any way to (auto) select the first item in the ListView after the collection has been filtered.

I've tried to set SelectedIndex=0, add both Target and Source notification to the binding, but all are ineffective when the filter applies.

Any pointers on how to achieve this?

EDIT: Below code illustrates my issue I'd say.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CollectionViewTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CollectionViewTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- MENU -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Content="Numbers below 4" Click="Below4_Click" Width="100"/>
            <Button Content="Numbers below 7" Click="Below7_Click" Width="100"/>
            <Button Content="All numbers" Click="All_Click" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- LIST -->
        <ListView 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            SelectedIndex="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNumber, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Number}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.Resources>
        </ListView>

        <!-- DETAILS -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding SelectedNumber.Text}" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-Behind:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace CollectionViewTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MainViewModel vm;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vm = (MainViewModel)DataContext;
        }

        private void Below4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            vm.MenuFilter = f => f.Value < 4;
        }

        private void Below7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            vm.MenuFilter = f => f.Value < 7;
        }

        private void All_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            vm.MenuFilter = f => true;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace CollectionViewTest
{
    public class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Numbers = new ObservableCollection<Number>();
            NumberCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Numbers);
            NumberCollection.Filter = Filter;
            NumberCollection.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Value", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                Numbers.Add(new Number { Value = i, Text = $"This is number {i}." });

        }

        private Func<Number, bool> menuFilter;
        public Func<Number, bool> MenuFilter
        {
            get => menuFilter;
            set
            {
                menuFilter = value;
                NumberCollection.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private bool Filter(object item)
        {
            var number = (Number)item;
            return MenuFilter == null ? true : MenuFilter(number);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Number> Numbers { get; set; }
        public ICollectionView NumberCollection { get; set; }

        private Number selectedNumber;
        public Number SelectedNumber { get => selectedNumber; set => Set(ref selectedNumber, value); }
    }

    public class Number : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }

        private string text;
        public string Text { get => text; set => Set(ref text, value); }
    }

    public class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void Set<T>(ref T field, T newValue = default(T), [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            field = newValue;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, pressing one of the buttons changes the Filter and calls Refresh on the collection. What I would like to have, is that the first item in the list (here '0') is selected automatically which then would display the text "This is number 0" in the text in column 2.

I have tried both the SelectedIndex=0 and also MoveCurrentToFirst but nothing is selected.

Comment: Did you really try to set the SelectedIndex property of the ListView to 0? This should work.

Comment: Yes and it does not work when the filter changes. I'll try to make a test outside my context in the weekend, but the ICollectionView + ListView in my application here is pretty basic so I doubt it...but I shall return.

Comment: @mm8 Example added. Seems that setting SelectedIndex = 0 only works if I do not call ICollectionView.Refresh. But I have to in order to evaluate the filter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't set `SelectedIndex` when binding to an `ICollectionView`. Instead, set its `CurrentItem` via [MoveCurrentTo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview.movecurrentto?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [MoveCurrentToFirst()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.icollectionview.movecurrenttofirst):

```
myCollectionView.MoveCurrentTo(someItem);
...
myCollectionView.MoveCurrentToFirst();
```

Also, set [IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem) on your `ListView`:

```
<ListView IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ...
```

### Detect when filter is applied

When the filter is evaluated, the collection view is refreshed which in turn resets the collection. To detect this, listen for the `CollectionChanged` event and look for the `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` flag. Please refer to the `CollectionView` [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/CollectionView.cs,885) for more details.

Comment: myCollectionView.MoveCurrentToFirst()

Comment: But MoveCurrentToFirst and derived methods are something I need to invoke to make the change - not a setting. Afaik there is no way for me to know WHEN the filtering is done?

Comment: @l33t Please look at my updated example, I've tried to subscribe to the CollectionChanged event (not in example though). But calling MoveCurrentToFirst() does nothing apparently.

Comment: @l33t oops - I forgot IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem and then it seems to work! Let me just do some more testing...

Comment: @l33t yeah that did the trick.LisView needs IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem. Subscribe to CollectionChanged and call MoveCurrentToFirst. A bit convoluted but Works like a charm. Thanks.